# iOS custom url scheme not opening app Xcode 5

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm trying to open my app with a custom url scheme, and I can't figure out what's going on. When I type the scheme into Safari on the simulator after running the app, I get the following dialog:

[image]

In the Safari bar, I type "mycustomscheme://"

below is my `plist` :

[image]

**Edit:**

I forgot to method that I also have this method in my `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // Do something with the url here
    DLog(@"here");
    return YES;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I think it may be an `Xcode 5` thing? I needed to go the `Target` -> `Info` and add a url type. This it what is looks like now:

[image]

Note that this is now what my plist looks like:

[image]

Oddly enough, there is no entry for the url scheme?

Comment: After you add this, look back to your info.plist. It actually adds a similar property as in your first post. Check against the new one against your previous one to see what you did wrong.

Comment: View as source code ;) Clarification - find your info.plist in the project viewer and view it as source code

Comment: Yes but it should include the URL Types property

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629) for more information about Custom URL schemes.

You should use the same string that is in the `Item 0(mycustomscheme)` for the Url identifier's 3d part. In your case it should be look like `my.bundle.mycustomscheme`

Comment: thanks, but I actually already have that method in my Appdelegate file. I don't think that matters anyhow. I just want to open the app - no other info is getting passed.

Comment: I don't think that's true according to the tutorial you reference

Comment: Have you tried this? I have checked it in my app and tried it in your way. I got the same error as in yours. Then done in this way. It worked.

Comment: Check this [link](http://yashesh87.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/open-your-iphone-app-from-safari-browser-in-iphone-using-url-schemes/) also

Comment: I did try it that way, and it still didn't work :( I don't understand what's going on